# Correct usage of "and more generally"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

What I am trying to say: "It is important to design **efficient** selection algorithms **and more generally** **efficient** resource allocation algorithms". Note that the resource allocation algorithm include the selection algorithms.

Is the following sentence correct to express the above idea:

> It is important to design efficient selection algorithms and more generally resource allocation algorithms.

In other words, should I add another 'efficient' after 'and more generally'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding the original sentence is a little overloaded, so  I've tried to simplify it by separating its two ideas as:

"It's important to design efficient selection algorithms. It follows that resource algorithms -- of which selection algorithms are a subgroup -- also need to be designed for efficiency."

Comment: Agree.  Commas, or periods and dashes, are helpful to make the sentence more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If "generally" goes with "more" you should add the commas because the phrase "more generally," is not necessary.

You may remove them if you mean "... generally-resource ..."  (paraphrased forom comments by Teacher KSHuang)